# What is the difference of int and 'int' in python?

Tags: python

I'm doing my homework in python and I happen to meet a very tricky problem: the difference between int and 'int' in python? Here is the code:

```py
type(1) == 'int'
type(1) == int
```

and here is the result:

```
False
True
```

I firstly thought that maybe `'int'` here is purely a string, but later I used pd.DataFrame for another test:

```py
train_data.deposit # train_data is a pd.DataFrame and deposit is a column with dtype int
train_data.deposit.dtype == 'int'
train_data.deposit.dtype == int
```

and got the result:

```
True
True
```

So is there a difference between `int` and `'int'` in python, if so, what is it? Thank you so much for your kind answer.

Comment: `'int'` is a string with no more significance than `'potato'`. `int` is a type.

Comment: Your first example is quite obvious - `'int'` is just a string and `int` is the type. This can be easily checked by `print(type(int), type('int'))`. I am still confused though how the second example behaves. It seems that `dtype` knows to check the string representation of its type as well?

Comment: `'int'` is "purely a string". The fact that `numpy.Dtype` objects implement the `__eq__` operator to accept strings does not make `'int'` not a `str`, although, I can see why that would be confusing

Comment: @Tomerikoo yeah. `numpy` and `pandas` have a lot of baggage like this.  I guess it was meant to make things more convenient but IMO don't really provide much value and can be quite confusing to python programmers. Note, `dtype == int` doesn't really make much sense either

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was trying to find the implementation of an `__eq__` but got lost in the source files and it seems like it might be implemented in C level. It might have been implemented that way because of types like `'int64'` which probably needs to be written as a string...

Comment: @Tomerikoo well, `int` really makes no sense either. The only way it *should* work, imo, is `arr.dtype == np.dtype('int64')` because remember, `dtype`'s **aren't types**! i.e. `isinstance(np.dtype('int64'), type)` is false. But numpy's APIs weren't designed around conceptual purity, rather, they were much more inclined to support ease of use by many non-programmer specialists (e.g. scientists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

anything in quotes is a string.

type() in python returns the type of an object. So type(1) is the type int (integer) and the type int is equal to int. But the type int is not equal to 'int' the string.

## Onto the example with pandas:

pandas dtype does not return a python class. It returns an object, which can be checked to be a type. So the == operator in python can be defined for all objects (Method **eq**). And dtype can be compared with python buildin types and strings.

### Example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([i for i in range(10)],columns=["test"]).astype(int)
# df is now a pandas DataFrame with type dtype(int32) therefore:
type(df.test.dtype) # -> <class 'numpy.dtype[int32]'>
df.test.dtype == 'int' # True
df.test.dtype == int # True
```

## Further Information

To overwrite the equals method you have to define a **eq**(this, other) Method inside a class. Feel free to google or follow tutorials like [this one](https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-oop/python-__eq__/)